# Remove handled file in spring integration DSL flow

Tags: java, jpa, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have such simple flow which read the file from folder and convert the content of this file into several entities in the database (spring-integration-jpa). Just found out that I don't see a simple way how to remove the handled file from the source dir.

Here is the code

```
@Configuration
public class ImportConfiguration {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImportConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${source.dir.path}")
    private String sourceDirectoryPath;

    @Value("${dest.dir.path}")
    private String destDirectoryPath;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public MessageSource<File> sourceDirectory() {
        FileReadingMessageSource messageSource = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        messageSource.setDirectory(new File(sourceDirectoryPath));
        messageSource.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaUpdatingOutboundEndpointSpec jpaPersistHandler() {
        return Jpa.outboundAdapter(this.entityManagerFactory)
                .entityClass(Brand.class)
                .persistMode(PersistMode.PERSIST);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileMoveFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(sourceDirectory(), conf -> conf.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(2000)))
                .filter(msg -> ((File) msg).getName().endsWith(".txt"))
                .transform(new FileToStringTransformer())
                .split(s -> s.delimiters("\n"))
                .<String, Brand>transform(name -> {
                    Brand brand = new Brand();
                    brand.setName(name);
                    return brand;
                })
                .handle(jpaPersistHandler(), ConsumerEndpointSpec::transactional)
                .get();
    }
}
```

If you use `FileWritingMessageHandler` all is very straight forward because there is a method `setDeleteSourceFiles` but with JpaUpdatingOutboundEndpointSpec all is not as simple.

Answer (score 1):

Add an [`ExpressionEvaluatingAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#expression-advice) to the `.handle()`.

There's an example [in the samples repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more) - xml, but the same techniques apply with the DSL.

Comment: The `FileReadingMessageSource` provides for us a `FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE` header. To remove the file is just a simple call of `delete()` from that header.

Comment: Right `setOnSuccessExpressionString(headers['file_originalFile'].delete());`